# svcutil ignores WS-Trust Claims

Tags: wcf, webservice-client, svcutil.exe, sts-securitytokenservice

Scenario: I am writing a WCF client to access a Java/Metro webservice which requires authentication through a token obtained from an STS (also Java/Metro). The relevant policy snippet from the service's WSDL is this:

```
<sp:IssuedToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
  <sp:Issuer>
    <wsa:Address>...</wsa:Address>
    <Metadata xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
      <Metadata xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex">
        <MetadataSection>
          <MetadataReference>
            <Address xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">...</Address>
          </MetadataReference>
        </MetadataSection>
      </Metadata>
    </Metadata>
  </sp:Issuer>
  <t:Claims Dialect="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity">
    <ClaimType xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity" Optional="false" Uri="..."/>
    <ClaimType xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity" Optional="false" Uri="..."/>
  </t:Claims>
  <sp:RequestSecurityTokenTemplate>
    <t:KeyType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/SymmetricKey</t:KeyType>
    <t:KeySize>256</t:KeySize>
  </sp:RequestSecurityTokenTemplate>
  <wsp:Policy>
    <sp:RequireDerivedKeys/>
    <sp:RequireInternalReference/>
  </wsp:Policy>
</sp:IssuedToken>
```

Note the `<Claims>` part **outside** the `<RequestSecurityTokenTemplate>`, as defined in WS-SecurityPolicy 1.2 (this has changed from the previous version where the `<Claims>` were placed within).

When placed like that, `svcutil` ignores the `<Claims>` entirely. When placed within the RST template though, they are copied into the generated config:

```
<binding ...>
  <security ...>
    <issuedTokenParameters ...>
      <additionalRequestParameters>
        <!-- The RST template is copied here -->
      </additionalRequestParameters>
      ...
    </issuedTokenParameters>
  </security>
  ...
</binding>
```

WCF claims (no pun intended) to support WS-SecurityPolicy **1.2**, so I wonder -- is this a bug oder by design? IMHO, the claims from the policy should **always** appear in the `<additionalRequestParameters>` of the binding configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Support confirmed to me that this is a bug in .NET 4.0 and a fix is planned for the next version.